# SymPy's evalf incorrect when rounding

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to compute the percentage error between two numbers, and SymPy is behaving weirdly.

I have (using SymPy version 1.12):

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.units import *

true_time = convert_to(year, seconds)
approx_time = pi * 10**7 * second
```

And I want to calculate the percentage error between `approx_time` and `true_time`, using 2 significant digits.

If I use:
`(100.0*((true_time - approx_time) / true_time)).evalf(2)` the result is 0.52, but should be 0.45.

I can force the correct result by using an extra evalf:
`(100.0*((true_time - approx_time) / true_time)).evalf().evalf(2)`
but it seems this should not be necessary (based on my understanding of evalf from the SymPy documentation).

As an alternate approach I would have also expected this to work:

```
convert_to((true_time - approx_time) / true_time, percent).evalf(2)
```

but this evaluates to: `0.49*percent*second`. The coefficient is incorrect, and `second` should have been cancelled out and not appear in the result.

Is this a SymPy bug, or very unintuitive behavior? Is there a more canonical way to calculate percentage error in SymPy?

Comment: for those of who cam't run the code show the intermediate values.  The times, their diffrence, the plain eval, etc.  In other words, do some debugging for us.

Comment: I think this is a bug in `evalf`. The simplest form I could put it in is `s = symbols('s'); print(((3.2 * s - pi * s)/s).evalf(3))` that gives `0.0591` instead of `0.0584`. As a workaround I suppose one can always use `expr.evalf().evalf(2)` to evaluate first with 15 digits and then round off to the intended precision.

Comment: `evalf` docs says `Evaluate the given formula to an accuracy of *n* digits.` That's not the same as rounding the result to those digits. I don't know how it evaluates, but the other parameters suggest it is not just a simplify() followed by a numerical substitution.

Comment: A relevant `evalf(3)` closed issue, https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21807.  It suggests using `round`